# GM_addStyle with dynamic class name?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I have an Website which contains something like this:

```
<div class="yqCWmB">
   <img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" src="//www.golem.de/1903/sp_Vllz-744275_rc.jpg" style="position: fixed; top: 87px;">
</div>
```

where this "yqCWmB" in the class name is dynamically created.

When I use: `GM_addStyle(".'yqCWmB' {visibility: hidden !important; }");` that element is hidden, but next time that class name is something like "zCNfYMo" and the element is not hidden anymore.
How can I search for that dynamic class name? I'm using this in an Greasemonkey Script.

That `<img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"` inside the DIV is always the same, maybe find somehow with that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `div[class]:has(>img[referrerpolicy]) { display: none !important }` in Chrome 105+ and Firefox 121+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `referrerpolicy` attribute along with its value to hide the div.

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).find('img[referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"]').closest('div').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yqCWmB">
   <img referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" src="//www.golem.de/1903/sp_Vllz-744275_rc.jpg" style="position: fixed; top: 87px;">
   <p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]